# Coding problems when define something, but can't plot them

Tags: python, numpy, plot

```
import numpy as N
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
def function2(t):
    if (t-N.floor(t))<0.5:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1

def function3(t):
    if t<=5:
        return N.cos(40*N.pi*t)
    else:
        return 0

x2= N.linspace(0,10,1024)
y2= function2(x2)

x3= N.linspace(0,40,8192)
y3= function3(x3)

plt.plot(x2,y2)
plt.show()
```

No matter I try `plot(x2,y2)` or `(x3,y3)`, it shows error message, but I can print any single value of `function2` and `function3` without any problems.

I'm stuck here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are having:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 16, in <module>
    y2= function2(x2)
  File "b.py", line 4, in function2
    if (t-N.floor(t))<0.5:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

which comes from the line:

```
if (t-N.floor(t))<0.5:
```

Here you are doing if `array < 0.5`. What is your intent?

If you want to check all elements of the array > 0.5, you can:

```
all(array < 0.5)
```

Comment: My intent here is to make a rectangular wave between -1 and 1 whose period is 0.5s, Like for 5.6, 5.6-5>0.5, so function2(5.6)=1; and for 6.4, 6.4-6<0.5, so function2(6.4)=-1

Answer (score 0):

`function2` and `function3` is a scalar function. You need to convert them into vectorized one:

```
x2 = N.linspace(0,10,1024)
y2 = N.vectorize(function2)(x2)

x3 = N.linspace(0,40,8192)
y3 = N.vectorize(function3)(x3)
```

See [`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but I'm still confused why it needs to be vectornized. Is it because I have if statement in the definition? But also why does just printing out the value of some number work just fine?

Comment: @Luker, What do you expect from `(t-N.floor(t))` ?

Comment: My intent here is to make a rectangular wave between -1 and 1 whose period is 0.5s, Like for 5.6, 5.6-5>0.5, so function2(5.6)=1; and for 6.4, 6.4-6<0.5, so function2(6.4)=-1

Comment: @Luker, But the code in the question passes an array instead of a number.

Comment: Thanks @falsetru, but how can I convert that array to a number I need?

Comment: @Luker, Like what I did in the answer. For the `function2`, it would be possible to Convert True -> -1, False -> 1. But, for `function3`, it's not possible without knowing the original value `t`.

Answer (score 0):

What you were doing, was applying `array` comparison, which gives you an array of True/False. So your `if` function evaluates to both at the same time. That raises an error.

While the solution proposed @falsetru is acceptable, I strongly advise against using `vectorize`, since it adds unnecessary for loops. Instead you can utilize the strength of numpy to do simple comparison operations above. Example: if `a` is an array `(a>0)` returns an element-wise boolean array with `True`(1) or `False`(0), which later can be operated on. Your code should look like this:

```
def function2(t):
   return 1-2*(t-N.floor(t)<0.5)   # returns 1- 2*True(1)/False(0)

def function3(t):
   return (t<=5)*N.cos(40*pi*t)    # returns 0 if t<=5 evaluates to False


x2= N.linspace(0,10,1024)
y2= function2(x2)

x3= np.linspace(0,40,8192)
y3= function3(x3)

plt.plot(x2,y2)
ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
```